# Perl - Search and replace a hash value in another file

Tags: perl, hash, replace

I am creating a mini program to find a specific hash key and to replace its source, but to do this I need to find the whole hash and replace it with a new hash the values the user input.

Example of my code.

```
print "Please input the smile you would like to edit: ";
$EditSmile = <STDIN>;
print "Please input the text you want to change: ";
$EditText = <STDIN>;

open (IN, "< info.pl") || die("Can not open file: $!");

while (<IN>){
    $var1 =~ s/\'$EditSmile\' => "$smileinfo{"$EditSmile"}"/\'$EditSmile\' => "$EditText"/g;
    print $var1;    
}
```

Where the hash values are in the file `info.pl`, which is included in the program.

Comment: Please don't read in a perl script like it was a data file and attempt to parse it by hand. If it is valid perl, simply execute it and let Perl parse it for you.

Comment: The hash its like a db i am storing some information which later need to be added, deleted or edited. this is why i need to do this.

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` I suspect you will also want to `chomp` your input.

Comment: Hi,

The issue is i am not a pro in perl :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your while should read

```
while ($var1 = <IN>) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I dont think its a valid statement :)

Comment: but it is. If you do now use "$var1" in the while, then you will need to use $_ for the substitution.

Comment: Hi,

Well i did ti now but the ourput is like this:

':)' => ":)",
         ':-)--' => "1':)
' => "TEST
"':)
' => "TEST

And this is the code:

while ($var1 = <IN>){
   
   $var2 = chomp($_);
   
   $var1 =~ s/$var2/\'$EditSmile\' => \"$EditText\"/g;
    
    print OUT $var1; 
   }

Answer (score 0):

Another option, as Ether suggested above, is to "do" your pl file and change the hash directly.

```
my $hash = do "info.pl";
if (exists($hash->{$EditSmile})) {
    $hash->{$EditSmile} = $EditText;
}
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($hash);
```

Comment: Well its outputing $var1 !! why ?